# Why does a destructor crash my program?

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I am interfacing some C++ code with Python.

Here's the C++:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {

struct buf {
  buf(char* p, int len) : p_(strdup(p)), len_(len) { }
  char *p_;
  int len_;
  ~buf() { }
};

buf foo(char* h)
{
  return buf(h, strlen(h));
} }
```

And here's the Python:

```
from ctypes import *
import struct
class buf(Structure):
  _fields_ = [("buf", c_char_p), ("len", c_int)]

d = cdll.LoadLibrary('./foo.so')
d.foo.restype = buf
b = d.foo('hello world')
print b.buf
print b.len
```

This code causes seg fault. However, if I comment out the destructor in struct buf, there is no crash. Something wrong with Python gc?

Comment: By the way, you are leaking memory. `strdup` in your constructor allocates memory, and your destructor does not clean it up.

Comment: Can you use destructors in `extern "C"`?

Comment: I don't know if I can use destructors in extern "C" but the compiler did not warn or error out. As for leaking, I know I have to use free but the mere presence of the destructor is cause for crash.

Comment: @Fanatic23 the compiler doesn't warn, even if you use `virtual` functions (which are clearly non-portable to C code due to the vtable/vpointer being implementation dependent). My guess is that the destructor is not allowed, although I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings.  Mine warns that `buf` is incompatible with C-linkage.

Comment: Using `extern "C"` on `foo` is incorrect because you're returning a C++ class instance by value, i.e. with the destructor the struct is no longer treated as plain old data. This forces a `thiscall`, whereas for a struct of this size ctypes expects a POD value to be returned in a combination of `rax` and `rdx` (System V AMD64 ABI) and so doesn't allocate the buffer and pass the pointer in `rsi`. If you make the structure larger (and modify the `ctypes.Structure`) it works even with a destructor defined because ctypes passes the (now required) implicit pointer as a hidden initial parameter.